# ODE when a parameter follows a probability distribution

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Consider the following pair of differential equations

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= b y - a x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= a x - b y
\end{align}

Now assume that the parameter $a$ is random according to some probability distribution $f_a$.

**Question:** Is the above system of equations still considered a differential equation when a parameter is random? Does this fall into a class/type of differential equations? Any pointers to relevant literature is appreciated.

Comment: Is $a$ a fixed value for any single instance of the system? Are you trying to examine something about how the system behaves as $a$ varies?

Comment: @ConMan $a$ is a random variable. I’m trying to analyze the distribution of solutions of the system of equations given that $a$ follows a probability distribution $f_a$. Is it correct to suppose that the set of solutions is also dictated by a probability distribution?

Comment: Yes? For any fixed $a$, the system has a particular solution. So you have a space of solutions parameterised by $a$, so you can talk about the distribution of those solutions. If $x$ were meant to be a random distribution as well then you'd be drifting into stochastic calculus, but I'm pretty sure that you don't have to worry about that here because you're essentially taking deterministic functions of $a$ which is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @ConMan Thanks! Do you know if this sort of system falls within a known class of equations? I suppose it’s like an SDE but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Since the DEs are both linear in $x$ and $y$, it's easily covered under simple linear ODEs (also, the equation as written has $\dot{x} = -\dot{y}$ which means that $x = C - y$ and your system collapses pretty quickly, is that what you meant to write?)

Comment: I was trying to show a simple system of equations for illustration purposes but it seems I’ve taken it too far :) I didn’t intend to place such strict simplifying restrictions...the equations are allowed to be nonlinear. I’m interested in the class of equations where some coefficients can be random. Some digging in the meantime has revealed that some people refer to these as “random differential equations.”